# Using outcome of MySQL query as WHERE clause for next

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I would like to use the following MySql query as an input for the WHERE clause in the main query, but I cannot find the correct way to do this. Is there any site or example I can use in order to learn how to do this?

Code is as follows:

MAIN Query:

```
SELECT *, IF(SubQuery is true, 'Yes', 'No') AS Watched Distribution
FROM account
WHERE Watched Distribution LIKE 'Yes'
```

SubQuery:

```
SELECT account_id, IF(w.main_title RLIKE 'place holder for film 
titels|nextfilm|nextfilm', 'Distribution', 'Non-distribution') AS Distribution
FROM watched w
WHERE Distribution LIKE 'Distribution'
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: I know! Due to new GDPR related policy, it is hard to share this data.. I understand that this put me in a tight spot, so any direction towards some documentation or lessons on how to use subqueries in a new query would help me a lot as well.

Comment: . . So you make up sample data.  We don't want *real* data, just examples to illustrate what you intend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use JOIN operator and where clause like this:

```
SELECT a.*, 'Yes'
FROM account a
JOIN watched w on w.account_id = a.account_id
where 'Distribution' in (IF(w.main_title RLIKE 'place holder for film 
titels|nextfilm|nextfilm', 'Distribution', 'Non-distribution'))
```

See example below:

https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/mysql-question-how-to-us-an-as-field-in-the-where-clause/1188/5